# String fuzzy lookup

Tags: search, data-structures, language-agnostic

This is an interview question.

Given a file consisting of names, what data structure would you use to validate whether a name is in the list. What if we say a name is valid if it differs by no more than one character against a name in the file?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that it depends on the context: if you have millions of names, a contract to fulfil and a product that does it for you, then I'd say go for it and forget about writing it yourself.

However, in the context of an interview question, my suggestion would be a [DAWG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_word_graph) that contains all possible mistakes.

A long time ago I heard that spell-checkers contain a list of words with possible mistakes (instead of trying to match against a list of valid words), but I don't know how true that is.

I did work once on a problem of finding a word in a list of words (with mistakes), but it wasn't restricted to a single mistake, and not a lot of memory was available. So the words were simply stored as a list (a DAWG requires nodes and pointers which would have required too much overhead).

Comment: That will result in pretty large space overhead: 2*size of alphabet*number of words. Depending on the exact requirements it might be better to store the valid words and check deviation of the input.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest storing the names from the file into a trie or DAWG (better space efficiency).
Upon name arrival, start traversing the data structure. You'll have 4 variants:

1. Name found --> name is valid
2. Dead end in the data structure --> check number of characters left in the name, if no more than 1 --> name is valid; invalid otherwise.
3. Name ended and haven't arrived to a leaf in the structure --> check if there is at least one leaf attached to the current position (will take O(size of the alphabet)) --> if so, name is valid; invalid otherwise.
4. Difference encountered in the middle of the word --> continue traversing from the next character --> no more errors allowed (paragraphs 2 & 3 aren't valid anymore from this point).

Answer (score 1):

For the first question (exact search), you can use a hash table or a trie.  Bloom filters may tell you "No" earlier with a space overhead, but can never tell you a definite "Yes."

For the second question (fuzzy search), much more advanced techniques are needed.  Check the blog at http://blog.srch2.com/2012/03/fuzzy-search.html to discuss different solutions to this problem.